# Python datetime.timezone for negative timezone

Tags: python, datetime

Here is my test code

```
datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(minutes=-495)))
```

and it returned

```
2017-12-02T19:07:09-0815
```

Shouldn't it be -0845 instead?

Comment: 495 minutes is 8 hours and 15 minutes.  Why would you expect that to be rendered as `0845`?

Comment: My bad than, thank you for clarification